# Google does not index my main page

Tags: redirects, search-engine-indexing, noindex

I was trying to index the main page of my site but it is not successful because I have a url with noindex and some redirected pages. Why is this influencing the main url ?
[image]

Comment: If it says it then there are problems. We need more details.

Comment: Please post the `head` part of the main_url and portions on links on other pages that reference the main site.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a new site then you have to wait months for it to be indexed fully.  In this period any errors on any of the pages will delay the indexing.

You have to make sure that you fix all the problems the GSE reports.  And make sure that your `html` and `css` do not have errors.  There are many sites around to check that for you.  There are even browser extensions that will check it.

The way to check if your site is indexed or not is to use  `site:olifel.pt` in Google Search.  When I do that, it appears that your main page is indexed after all.

[image]